# Setting state parameter to a Stripe query to pass a FireStore uuid

Tags: firebase, https, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am trying to pass a FirebaseFirestore User Uid to a Stripe / firestore cloud function.

So I would have an https query like following :

[https://connect.stripe.com/express/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={accountid}&scope=read_write](https://connect.stripe.com/express/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=%7Baccountid%7D&scope=read_write) to open in a Webview

Here is my function

```
exports.connectStripeExpressAccount = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) =>{
  console.log('query state is  ----> ' + req.query.state);
  const authCode = req.query.code;
  return stripe.oauth.token({
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    code: authCode,
  }).then(async response => {
      var connected_account_id = response.stripe_user_id;
      const uid = req.query.state
      const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection('Registration').doc(uid)
                           .set({'customer_id': connected_account_id});
      return res.send("Well done, account integration is completed. You can now close the window and go back to the app");
      });
});
```

Comment: Where are you calling the URL with the `client_id` query string parameter? Your code shows an HTTP Cloud Function, that will be exposed by an URL but this URL is not `https://connect.stripe.com/express...`. So where are you building and calling the `https://connect.stripe.com/...` URL with the `client_id` query string parameter?

Comment: the url is called from a flutter app using a Webview, in the url I provided, I ve just replace the real stripe clientId with {clientId} in order to hide it. Accessing this url to stripe launches a default function witch is set to be connectStripeExpressAccount

Comment: What is not clear is how the `connectStripeExpressAccount` Cloud Function is connected to the other steps? Is it exposed as a webhook that Stripe calls? In other words: you write "Accessing this url to stripe launches a default function witch is set to be connectStripeExpressAccount" but how does your "system" (i.e. Flutter app + Stripe + Cloud Function backend) launches the Cloud Function?

Comment: technically yes, on the stripe side you define a URI that connects straight to your cloud function. when the URL request has no parameters, it automatically connects to this URI

Comment: You should explain much more precisely how the different components (i.e. Flutter app + Stripe + Cloud Function backend) interact between each other and which info/payload is transmitted for each event. I have the feeling that from your Flutter app you call Stripe with a user ID and you want Stripe to pass this user ID when calling back your Cloud Function, but this is not clear.

Comment: My bad, this was a Stripe / https aware question. The thing is passing a state parameter to a url should be straightforwrard, just adding &state=something to your url. the way flutter / stripe / / cloud functions / firestore works is also straightforward. On the flutter side, a webview with an url built to access stripe connect (the url I have above) / the cloud function adress is provided to stripe as a webhook URI / when you Oauth connect to stripe, it will automatically launch this CF webhook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For new integrations with Express Accounts you should ideally be using the [Account Links functionality](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts) instead of OAuth.  That said, if you provide the `state` value, it should carry through, so I'd make sure you're actually providing it when opening the WebView.

Answer (score 0):

If the User uid is stored in the query parameter `state` and the URL looks like this:
https://connect.stripe.com/express/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ca_JCV8JW9ZIjBaGkwkhbDDDQegceWGidqh&scope=read_write&state=useruidxxx

Your code would look like this:

```js
exports.connectStripeExpressAccount = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) =>{
  console.log('query state is  ----> ' + req.query.state);
  const authCode = req.query.code;
  return stripe.oauth.token({
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    code: authCode,
  }).then(async response => {
      var connected_account_id = response.stripe_user_id;
      const uid = req.query.state
      const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection('Registration').doc(uid)
                           .set({'customer_id': connected_account_id});
      return res.send("Well done, account integration is completed. You can now close the window and go back to the app");
      });
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain more what you want to achieve and what the problem is? Maybe I did not understand correctly what the issue here is. A brief explanation how your code works and how it should work and where in the workflow you have your issue would help us understand your problem.

Comment: ClientId is the StripeClientID, I would like to add a State parameter to the URL, something like https://connect.stripe.com/express/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ca_JCV8JW9ZIjBaGkwkhbDDDQegceWGidqh&scope=read_write#&state=useruidxxx

Comment: I have updated the answer. Hope it's better now.

Comment: that s exactly what I have done, but I still have a non defined state query parameter in my log ... so weird

Comment: Can you write a `console.log(req.query)` and check all params with it.

Comment: Could you also try to rename the param from `state` to `user_uid`. Maybe `state` is a reserved name.